# extracting individual data after selecting with querySelectorAll

Tags: javascript

Say I have the following HTML that I wish to extract data from (i have 100s of these but only took in two to make an example):

```html
<div id="g_36_rw7urqL5" title="Click for match detail!"
     class="event__match event__match--static event__match--last event__match--twoLine"><span
        class="event__check--hidden"></span>
    <div class="event__time">12.04. 23:00</div>
    <div class="event__participant event__participant--home fontBold">Team 1
        <svg class="winner___FkdGI2I icon icon--winner"><title></title>
            <use xlink:href="/res/_fs/build/symbols.b5303d6.svg#winner"></use>
        </svg>
    </div>
    <div class="event__participant event__participant--away">Team 2</div>
    <div class="event__score event__score--home">3</div>
    <div class="event__score event__score--away">0</div>
</div>
<div id="g_36_ObXZ7s3e" title="Click for match detail!"
     class="event__match event__match--static event__match--last event__match--twoLine"><span
        class="event__check--hidden"></span>
    <div class="event__time">12.04. 16:30</div>
    <div class="event__participant event__participant--home fontBold">Team 1
        <svg class="winner___FkdGI2I icon icon--winner"><title></title>
            <use xlink:href="/res/_fs/build/symbols.b5303d6.svg#winner"></use>
        </svg>
    </div>
    <div class="event__participant event__participant--away">Team 2</div>
    <div class="event__score event__score--home">3</div>
    <div class="event__score event__score--away">2</div>
</div>
```

Now i am trying to get a hang of using the `querySelectorAll` and how i can loop through the elements to find what i need. I have attempted the following:

```
const eventMatch = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.event__match'))
return eventMatch.map(td => {
    const homeTeam = td.find('.event__participant--home');
});
```

However, this doesn't work since what the `querySelector` returns is an element which means the "find" method won't work.

What is the best way to search through all of these elements and extracting the data?

My goal is to get the data out as such:

```
Match:

Team 1, Team 2, score: 3,0
```

For each of the matches these will later on be put into a database

Comment: What is the end goal?

Comment: @epascarello sorry i will edit the my question

Comment: find is for an array, it is not DOM method.

Comment: @epascarello i see is there a way i can select these using dom methods?

Comment: replace find with querySelector?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just `.querySelectorAll()` and loop over the `div` elements that represent the matches and then `.querySelector()` within the match for the specific classes - - no need to map.

```js
document.querySelectorAll("[title='Click for match detail!']").forEach(function(match){
  let result = "";
  result += match.querySelector(".event__participant--home").textContent.trim() + ", " ;
  result += match.querySelector(".event__participant--away").textContent.trim() + ", " ;
  result += "score: " + match.querySelector(".event__score--home").textContent.trim() + "," ;
  result += match.querySelector(".event__score--away").textContent.trim();  
  console.log(result);
});
```

```html
<div id="g_36_rw7urqL5" title="Click for match detail!"
     class="event__match event__match--static event__match--last event__match--twoLine"><span
        class="event__check--hidden"></span>
    <div class="event__time">12.04. 23:00</div>
    <div class="event__participant event__participant--home fontBold">Team 1
        <svg class="winner___FkdGI2I icon icon--winner"><title></title>
            <use xlink:href="/res/_fs/build/symbols.b5303d6.svg#winner"></use>
        </svg>
    </div>
    <div class="event__participant event__participant--away">Team 2</div>
    <div class="event__score event__score--home">3</div>
    <div class="event__score event__score--away">0</div>
</div>
<div id="g_36_ObXZ7s3e" title="Click for match detail!"
     class="event__match event__match--static event__match--last event__match--twoLine"><span
        class="event__check--hidden"></span>
    <div class="event__time">12.04. 16:30</div>
    <div class="event__participant event__participant--home fontBold">Team 1
        <svg class="winner___FkdGI2I icon icon--winner"><title></title>
            <use xlink:href="/res/_fs/build/symbols.b5303d6.svg#winner"></use>
        </svg>
    </div>
    <div class="event__participant event__participant--away">Team 2</div>
    <div class="event__score event__score--home">3</div>
    <div class="event__score event__score--away">2</div>
</div>
```